# Why wont Material UI xs={12} fill full width of screen on mobile?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7N1Z.jpg)

My components which are all xs={12} Grid components and should be filling up my whole mobile screen are not, and seem to have an invisible margin on the right.

```
    <React.Fragment>
  <CssBaseline />
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Grid container direction='column'>
        <Grid container justifyContent='center'>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={10}>
              <Header connectWallet={connectWallet}/>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid container justifyContent='center' alignItems='center'>
          <Grid item sx={{minHeight: 'calc(100vh - 400px)'}} xs={12} sm={10}>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/bouquets">
                <Bouquets />
              </Route>
              <Route path='/about'>
                <About />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/">
                <Home />
              </Route>
            </Switch>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Footer/>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </ThemeProvider>
</React.Fragment>
```

Comment: You sure your screen fits into the xs media query and not the sm media query?

Comment: Make sure your `html` and `body` as well as `#root` elements are styled as `width: 100%`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <Grid
        container
        item
        sx={{
         backgroundColor: '#FFF',
         minHeight: {
            xs: '100vh',
            md: 'auto',
           xl: 'auto',
           lg: 'auto'
         },
width: { xs: "100%", md: "auto", xl: 'auto',
           lg: 'auto' } 
        }}
    >
        <Grid item xs={8}>
        <Item>xs=8</Item>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
        <Item>xs=4</Item>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).